# Eclipse in Linux opaque whitespace characters

Tags: linux, eclipse, user-interface, fonts, opacity

I'm running `Eclipse` on `Gentoo Linux`:

```
Linux stanws 3.8.13-gentoo #1 SMP Mon May 27 15:55:36 ICT 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
[ebuild   R   ~] dev-util/eclipse-sdk-3.7.1-r11:3.7::seden
```

Here's an issue that I've got:

In **Window >> Preferences >> General >> Editors >> Text Editors** I enable **Show whitespace characters** option, then I change **Transparency level** to any value except 255, but whitespace characters stay opaque!

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y5hB.png)

I need them to be slightly visible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by installing Eclipse Kepler